# jQuery UI Tabs: change a div using a data attribute via a bind event *broken*

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

Should be easy, but I've got a few things broken here I can't figure out - **jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/8muBm/9/

What I'm trying to do is bind the tab change to change an image using a data attribute. (I need to use bind as I need to add this to another function that also uses bind.)

But getting this to work escapes me right now....

```
$('#tabs').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {

var $tabs= $("#tabs").tabs();

var img = $(ui.panel).data("image");
$("#headerwrapper")
.animate({ opacity: 'toggle' }, function() {
$(this).css("background-image", "url(" + img + ")")
.animate({ opacity: 'toggle' });
});
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here http://jsfiddle.net/pSDqh/

Changes:

- Take the tab initializer out of the
  event.
- A few broken }, )

*Update*:

- Improved animation so it won't blackout.
- Placed script inside load event, to ensure initialization.

---

If you don't want to use tabs(), only use the links, it's here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jayea/

Comment: Thanks, that works with `$("#tabs").tabs();`  but I can't use that init in my code. I need it to work with what I have in my jsfiddle.

Comment: you will not use the tabs then, only the links ? can you move the urls to the links?

Comment: it won't work because tabsshow event only exists after a tabs(), and as you said, you can't use tabs()

Comment: updated.. please check. please try to init all inside a $(function() {})

Answer (score 0):

```
var $tabs= $("#tabs").tabs();


$('#tabs').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {
    var img = $(ui.panel).data("image");
    $("#headerwrapper").animate({ opacity: 'toggle' }, function() {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + img + ")").animate({ opacity: 'toggle' });
});
});
```

Comment: Try this JS instead. Worked for me!

Comment: Thanks, and that works somewhat, but.... the header image flashes opacity, over and over. And I need `$('#tabs').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {` to be above `var $tabs= $("#tabs").tabs();
` becuase of a jQuery bug.

Comment: To bind to the tabshow event the tabs need to be initialized. I don't see that as a bug. I guess I didn't get the point of your animate (for the image).